# Weird cylindrical deadbolt housing

Tags: removal, old-house, deadbolt

I am trying to change the locks in my house, and saw this weird housing for the old deadbolt.  To me it looks like glued on as there are no screws or indentations, but is there any other way?

Adding more pictures. I apologize that the lighting is poor, and those shapes on the inside may look like screws, but they aren’t.

If it is in fact glued,

How do I remove this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about pictures looking into it from both sides.

Comment: Thanks for responding Jack. Have added more pics. Those shapes on the inside aren’t screws, so really am wondering how to get this thing out.

Comment: Try turning it with a pair of Channelocks  or adjustable pliers.

Comment: it has to be threaded therefore JACK's response is a good one

Answer (score 3):

Everyone of those that i have encountered as just be pushed in.

Sometimes they are held in by friction and sometime they are loose and fall out.

It could be that is a snug fit and when the screws that held the two halve of  the lock together were tightened up it wedged it in rather tightly.

Comment: Put a long nail through the door so that it presses on the inside of the cylinder and give it a few taps with a hammer to see if it starts to move. You may need to tap it a 12 o'clock, 3, 6 & 9 o'clock in a regular rotation to get it to press out evenly.

Comment: Why should they tap it a 3 hour intervals? ;) Oh,wait, you meant the 12 o'clock position. Why not 12 and 6 then 3 and 9?

Comment: Point being to tap it out evenly so it doesn't jam by banging on only 1 side. One could choose the 1, 4:15, 7:23 & 11 o'clock positions, should one choose...